# How to add hover effect or mouseover/mousenter effect in a country map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">
<div id="app" >
  <svg ref="svg" height="600" width="1300">
   <path
     v-for="(state, index) in stateData"
     :d="pathGenerator(state.feature)"
     :style="{
       fill: state.color,
       stroke: 'darkslategray'
     }"  @mouseover="updateDetails(index)">
   </path>

 </svg>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/3.0.0/fetch.min.js.map"></script>

    <script src="sample.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selectedState:0,
    statesJson: {
 "here I i uploaded the map data in .json format"},
  methods:{
    updateDetails:function(index)
    {
      this.selectedState = index
    //  return this.statesJson.features[this.selectedState].id
      console.log(this.selectedState)
      console.log(this.statesJson.features[this.selectedState].id)

    }
  },

  computed: {
    // Typical projection for showing all states scaled and positioned appropriately
    projection () {
      return d3.geoMercator().scale(900).translate([-500, 600])
    },

  /* updateName(){
      return this.statesJson.features[this.selectedState].id
      console.log(this.selectedState)
    },*/

    // Function for converting GPS coordinates into path coordinates
    pathGenerator () {
      return d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection)
    },

    // Combine the states GeoJSON with a rank-based gradient
    stateData () {
      return this.statesJson.features.map(feature => {
        
        return {
          feature,
          color: this.stateColor(feature.rank)
        }
      })
    },


    // Interpolate from red to green in the domain 50 to 1 (our ranking)
    stateColor () {
      return d3.scaleSequential().domain([50,1]).interpolator(d3.interpolateRdYlGn)
    }

  }
})
```

In this Code I want to create hover effect to see the details when anyone hovers the mouse cursor on the state.

For just trial purpose I have embedded the Data but I will upload it using some api .
Can anyone tell that how to create this effect ?

The rank of the states which is the base to color a state is also taken in statesJson.

Comment: maybe its me, but when I run the snippet I get a bunch of errors in the console and a blank page

Comment: because I haven't add the data in statesJson . If you want I can give you that .json file from which I have copied the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is better solution : [Interactive map in vue with svg.js](https://blog.carbonteq.com/creating-interactive-map-in-vue-js/)

PREVIOUS POST :

Your can make this

```
const states = document.querySelectorAll("#svg path");
states.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        // show data box
    });
    el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        // Remove data box
    });
});
```

Your svg

```
<svg id="svg" ref="svg" height="600" width="1300">
    <g id="states">
        <path v-for="..."></path>
    </g>
 </svg>
```

Better, you can [create your own directive](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) to show box and use again it on other project or share

```
<svg ref="svg" height="600" width="1300">
    <g id="states">
        <path v-for="..." v-map-data="data"></path>
    </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: can you tell me what 'svgStates' refers in this code?

Comment: I think there is some mistake in the given solution . Please make sure that it is working correctly and reply back. I have checked this but it is not working.

Comment: Yes, there are one error (revised), but this work fine [codepen example](https://codepen.io/adx94/pen/LYpOVyy)

Comment: can you please tell me what should I write in the place of "// show data box" and "// Remove data box" to solve my problem?

Comment: This depend of what you want to do, `el` contains your path element who is hover, you can update its properties to change color, or scale or anything. if you want show a box with data, you can look [this example](https://codepen.io/adx94/pen/LYpOVyy). It show a box with data when path is hovered and the box follow the cursor